# Chart.js hover over label

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a bar chart in Chart.js (using the latest version), and I want to make some visual change when the mouse is hovering over a category label. How would I implement either or both of the following visual changes?

1. Make the cursor be a pointer while hovering over a label.
2. Make the label be in a different color while it is being hovered on.

A related question is here: [How to detect click on chart js 3.7.1 axis label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615569/how-to-detect-click-on-chart-js-3-7-1-axis-label). However, my question is about hovering over a label, without clicking on the label.

In the example below, I want something to happen when hovering on these texts: `Item A`, `Item B`, `Item C`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      indexAxis: 'y',
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.0"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the cursor a pointer while hovering over a label, you can try to assign a CSS cursor value to `event.native.target.style.cursor` when hover is triggered.

```
event.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

---

To make the label a different color while it is being hovered on, you can try this

```
myChart.config.options.scales.y.ticks.color = hoverColors; // ['black','red','black'], ['black','black','red'], ['red','black','black']
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee) for giving an almost correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75438712/12715723). I've edited the code above so it fits what is required in the problem. Don't forget to change source of the library in the HTML from :

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.0
```

to :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js
```

Updated code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const findLabel = (labels, evt) => {
      let found = false;
      let res = null;
      try {
          labels.forEach(l => {
              l.labels.forEach((label, index) => {
                  if (evt.x > label.x && evt.x < label.x2 && evt.y > label.y && evt.y < label.y2) {
                      res = {
                          label: label.label,
                          index
                      };
                      found = true;
                  }
              });
          });
      } catch (e) {}

      return [found, res];
  };

  const getLabelHitboxes = (scales) => {
      try {
          return Object.values(scales).map((s) => ({
              scaleId: s.id,
              labels: s._labelItems.map((e, i) => ({
                  x: e.translation[0] - s._labelSizes.widths[i],
                  x2: e.translation[0] + s._labelSizes.widths[i] / 2,
                  y: e.translation[1] - s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
                  y2: e.translation[1] + s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
                  label: e.label,
                  index: i
              }))
          }));
      } catch (e) {}
  };


  const changeCursorAndLabelColor = (event, chart, index, hoverMode) => {
      // your hover color here
      // const hoverColor = '#ff0000';
      const hoverColor = 'red';
      const hoverColors = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < myChart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
          if (hoverMode) {
              // change cursor
              event.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
              if (index === i) {
                  hoverColors.push(hoverColor);
              } else {
                  hoverColors.push(defaultLabelColor);
              }
          } else {
              // change cursor
              event.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
              hoverColors.push(defaultLabelColor);
          }
      }
      // change label to your hover color
      myChart.config.options.scales.y.ticks.color = hoverColors;

      // update chart when hover is triggered
      myChart.update();
  }

  let foundMode = false;
  const plugin = {
      id: 'customHover',
      afterEvent: (chart, event, opts) => {
          const evt = event.event;
          if (evt.type !== 'mousemove') {
              return;
          }
          const [found, labelInfo] = findLabel(getLabelHitboxes(chart.scales), evt);
          if (found && myChart.data.labels.includes(labelInfo.label)) {
              changeCursorAndLabelColor(evt, chart, labelInfo.index, true);
              foundMode = true;
          } else {
              if (foundMode) changeCursorAndLabelColor(evt, chart, null, false);
              foundMode = false;
          }

      }
  }

  Chart.register(plugin);
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'My Data',
              data: [1, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
          }]
      },
      options: {
          responsive: true,
          indexAxis: 'y',
          plugins: {
              legend: {
                  display: false
              },
              tooltip: {
                  enabled: false
              },
          },
          onHover: (event, chart) => {
              if (foundMode) changeCursorAndLabelColor(event, chart, null, false);
              foundMode = false;
          }
      }
  });
  const defaultLabelColor = myChart.config.options.scales.y.ticks.color;
};
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is about hovering over the label, not hovering over the bar.

Comment: Please check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the custom plugin from that question and ignore everything but mousemove events instead of ignoring everything but click events:

```js
const findLabel = (labels, evt) => {
  let found = false;
  let res = null;

  labels.forEach(l => {
    l.labels.forEach((label, index) => {
      if (evt.x > label.x && evt.x < label.x2 && evt.y > label.y && evt.y < label.y2) {
        res = {
          label: label.label,
          index
        };
        found = true;
      }
    });
  });

  return [found, res];
};

const getLabelHitboxes = (scales) => (Object.values(scales).map((s) => ({
  scaleId: s.id,
  labels: s._labelItems.map((e, i) => ({
    x: e.translation[0] - s._labelSizes.widths[i],
    x2: e.translation[0] + s._labelSizes.widths[i] / 2,
    y: e.translation[1] - s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
    y2: e.translation[1] + s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
    label: e.label,
    index: i
  }))
})));

const plugin = {
  id: 'customHover',
  afterEvent: (chart, event, opts) => {
    const evt = event.event;

    if (evt.type !== 'mousemove') {
      return;
    }

    const [found, labelInfo] = findLabel(getLabelHitboxes(chart.scales), evt);

    if (found) {
      console.log(labelInfo);
    }

  }
}

Chart.register(plugin);

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the cursor to a pointer when hovering over a category label in a Chart.js bar chart, you can add:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
  },
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false
  },
  onHover: function(evt, elements) {
    if (elements.length) {
      document.getElementById("myChart").style.cursor = "pointer";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myChart").style.cursor = "default";
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

To change the color of a label when it is being hovered on, you can add:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
  },
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false
  },
  onHover: function(evt, elements) {
    if (elements.length) {
      var chart = evt.chart;
      var datasetIndex = elements[0].datasetIndex;
      var index = elements[0].index;
      chart.data.labels[index] = '<span style="color: red;">' + chart.data.labels[index] + '</span>';
      chart.update();
    } else {
      var chart = evt.chart;
      chart.data.labels = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
      chart.update();
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```